# How to forbid a pointer to an object returned by a function from getting copied/assigned, yet still access the object's content?

Tags: c++

For example, I have a class `SomeClass` and two methods,
`SomeClass* getSomeClass()` and `SomeClass* assignSomeClass()`.

What I want is `getSomeClass()` to give me full access to the class' contents (variables and functions that are `public`), yet the pointer it returns shouldn't be allowed to be copied or assigned, eg `SomeClass* ptr = getSomeClass()` should be impossible, however `getSomeClass()->func()` should work fine.

Likewise, I want `assignSomeClass()` to allow the pointer to be assigned, but hide the object's content as much as possible, or prevent them from getting changed (maybe a better way than `SomeClass* assignSomeClass() const`?), eg `SomeClass* ptr = assignSomeClass()` should work, but `assignSomeClass()->func()` should not. Ideally `func()` should not be visible at all.

How can I do this?

In particular, the first case is what interests me the most.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you ask for is not possible. Though, if you explain why you think you need it, if you tell us about the actual problem you need to solve, then maybe we can propose a different solution

Answer (score 2):

You can't, and it's not your job to do so.

Since C++17 gave us guaranteed elision, even if your function returns a non-moveable wrapper object with an `operator->` overload, the caller will still be able to create a named variable of that type. There is absolutely nothing you can do about that.

Presumably, the pointer in question is owned in some way by the thing returning that pointer, and you want to prevent the caller from storing that object anywhere long-term. That's not a thing you can guarantee within the language. You *must* rely on the user not to use it improperly.

Also, since the function cannot return `nullptr`, you should return a reference.